# Linux port forwarding to Socks proxy

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, proxy

I've read a tutorial about a Raspberry Pi Project. In short, the project consists in a TOR middle box AP, that is connected to the internet via an Ethernet interface, and clients can connect to the raspberry Pi WLAN network through it's WiFi interface. All traffic coming to the WiFi interface is redirected to the local TOR SOCKS Proxy by using iptables port forwarding commands.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

Now my question is, how does the TOR socks proxy know the real socket destination port, as requested by the application?
For example, suppose that I'm using firefox to open stackvoerflow.com. Firefox makes a request to stackoverlfowIP:80 ..but iptables routes the request to localhost:9050, does the application knows that there is a SOCKS proxy in between (assuming that the proxy settings are NOT been set in the browser settings)? And how does the TOR local SOCKS proxy knows the real destination port, if the destination port has been changed from 80 to 9050 by iptables?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a kernel API ( `getsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, (struct sockaddr*) &orig_addr, sizeof(orig_addr))` )  available for the proxy to know the actually requested destination.

[A simple example daemon there](https://web.archive.org/web/20200115084842/http://svn.clifford.at/tools/trunk/examples/redir-daemon.c) (site disappeared, using Wayback Machine):

> [...]
>
> ```c
>         while (1) {
>                 int fd = CHECK(accept(listenfd,NULL, NULL), != -1);
>                 if (!fork()) {
>                         struct sockaddr_in trgaddr;
>                         size_t trgaddr_len = sizeof(trgaddr);
>                         CHECK(getsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, (struct sockaddr*)&trgaddr, &trgaddr_len), != -1);
>                         printf("Connection to port %d.\n", ntohs(trgaddr.sin_port));
>                         tcp_tunnel(fd, ntohs(trgaddr.sin_port));
>                         return 0;
>                 } else
>                         close(fd);
>         }
> ```
>
> [...]

By the way there's a new TPROXY target method that is more powerful than REDIRECT (can be transparent both ways), but requires additional setups (`--tproxy-mark` then needed by `ip rule fwmark ...` and the proxy now uses `setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &flag, sizeof(flag))` and then uses more standard methods than with REDIRECT). Not needed for TOR, but new applications might not be using REDIRECT anymore.

[TPROXY example](https://github.com/kristrev/tproxy-example)